# What's going to be new in bash 5

Tags: bash, upgrade

I was just going through the official bash repository(I don't usually do this) for something unrelated but noticed that bash 5 was already in beta. I was just curious about what's going to be new in bash 5 but couldn't find any information. Can someone  summarize the changes between 4.4 and 5 version of Bash

Comment: It's right there in the `CHANGES` file: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES?h=bash-5.0-testing

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The changes made to `bash` between release 4.4 and 5.0 (released 2019-01-07) may be found in the `NEWS` file in the `bash` source distribution.

[Here is a link to it](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS?h=bash-5.0) (the changes are too numerous to list here).

Comment: A short view shows the term `loadable builtins`. Does `bash` follow the new standard set up by `ksh93` to find enhanced builtins via `PATH` instead of giving them always priority?

Comment: @schily `bash` 4.4 and later uses `BASH_LOADABLES_PATH` and loads them from there with `enable -f builtin-name`.

Comment: Well, this seems to apply to the time when the command is loaded. What about about the time past that? `enable` looks like a reimplementation of the `ksh93` command `builtin` but it misses the feature to associate a path to every builtin command, which in `ksh93` is usually predefined by `/usr/ast/bin/<name>` and allows to have a fine grained control over all buiiltins.

Comment: @Kusalananda how can I get a new bash 5.0

Comment: @AnkurLoriya You wait until you Unix distributor ships it as a package, or you compile it yourself from sources.  The sources and the installation instructions are available on the [GNU Bash page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/).

Comment: @Kusalananda I compiled from source. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 21):

If you, like me, are looking for the headline features rather than the full changelog, [this post](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2019-01/msg00063.html) by the maintainer, Chet Ramey, goes over that. Here is the interesting section:

> This release fixes several outstanding bugs in bash-4.4 and introduces several
>   new features.  The most significant bug fixes are an overhaul of how
>   nameref variables resolve and a number of potential out-of-bounds memory
>   errors discovered via fuzzing. There are a number of changes to the
>   expansion of $@ and $* in various contexts where word splitting is not
>   performed to conform to a Posix standard interpretation, and additional
>   changes to resolve corner cases for Posix conformance.
>
> The most notable new features are several new shell variables: BASH_ARGV0,
>   EPOCHSECONDS, and EPOCHREALTIME. The `history' builtin can remove ranges of
>   history entries and understands negative arguments as offsets from the end
>   of the history list. There is an option to allow local variables to inherit
>   the value of a variable with the same name at a preceding scope. There is
>   a new shell option that, when enabled, causes the shell to attempt to
>   expand associative array subscripts only once (this is an issue when they
>   are used in arithmetic expressions).  The `globasciiranges' shell option
>   is now enabled by default; it can be set to off by default at configuration
>   time.
>
> There are a few incompatible changes between bash-4.4 and bash-5.0. The
>   changes to how nameref variables are resolved means that some uses of
>   namerefs will behave differently, though I have tried to minimize the
>   compatibility issues. By default, the shell only sets BASH_ARGC and
>   BASH_ARGV at startup if extended debugging mode is enabled; it was an
>   oversight that it was set unconditionally and caused performance issues
>   when scripts were passed large numbers of arguments.

He also refers to these two files, in case you want more:

- [NEWS](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS?h=bash-5.0): more detail (also in Kusalananda's answer)
- [CHANGES](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES?h=bash-5.0): most detail

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because of the posted summary.

Answer (score 6):

> The `history' builtin can remove ranges of history entries and understands negative arguments as offsets from the end of the history list.

Example on deleting a range:

```
history -d 123-130
```

or deleting the last 10:

```
history -d -10--1
```

Excerpt from [Bash 5 Man Page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.txt):

> 'history'
>
> Options, if supplied, have the following meanings:
>
> '-d OFFSET'
>       Delete the history entry at position OFFSET.  If OFFSET is
>       positive, it should be specified as it appears when the
>       history is displayed.  If OFFSET is negative, it is
>       interpreted as relative to one greater than the last history
>       position, so negative indices count back from the end of the
>       history, and an index of '-1' refers to the current 'history
>       -d' command.
>
> '-d START-END'
>       Delete the history entries between positions START and END,
>       inclusive.  Positive and negative values for START and END are
>       interpreted as described above.

See my related answer: [Delete a range of bash history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54224156/5012323)